# How Do I Get The Correct Duration Format For Media Player Duration?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the duration hours, minutes, and seconds from a playing Media Player in this format 00:00:00. Here's what I have so far. I almost have it, but it's not 100%.

```
 public String convertDurationMillis(Integer getDurationInMillis){

    int getDurationMillis = getDurationInMillis

    String convertHours = String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(getDurationMillis));
    String convertMinutes = String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(getDurationMillis));
    String convertSeconds = String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(getDurationMillis) -
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(getDurationMillis)));

    String getDuration = convertHours + ":" + convertMinutes + ":" + convertSeconds;

    return getDuration;

}
```

Here's my textview

```
myTV.setText(convertDurationMillis(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
```

It works fine as long as the audio duration is less than one hour. If the audio duration is equaled to or more than an hour this is my result...
02:149:51. How do I correct that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: check `android.text.format.DateUtils` documentation

Comment: ...specifically things like [`formatElapsedTime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#formatElapsedTime(long))

Comment: I tried those and I still didn't get the result I am wanting

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I finally got it! Here is the answer...

```
    public String convertDurationMillis(Integer getDurationInMillis){
    int getDurationMillis = getDurationInMillis;

    String convertHours = String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(getDurationMillis)); 
    String convertMinutes = String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(getDurationMillis) -
            TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(getDurationMillis))); //I needed to add this part.
    String convertSeconds = String.format("%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(getDurationMillis) -
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(getDurationMillis)));


    String getDuration = convertHours + ":" + convertMinutes + ":" + convertSeconds;

    return getDuration;

}
```

Thanks everyone!